TypeError: Safe.init is not a function
I am doing trying to initialize a new Protocol Kit as explained in this Safe tutorial:
https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit#confirm-the-transaction-second-confirmation
I have this piece of code
import Safe, {SafeConfig, SafeFactory} from "@safe-global/protocol-kit";

const protocolKit = await Safe.init({
        provider: RPC_URL,
        signer: OWNER_1_PRIVATE_KEY,
        safeAddress: SAFE_ADDRESS
    })

And when I run the code, it is returning this error:
const protocolKit = await Safe.init({
                               ^
TypeError: Safe.init is not a function

I don't understand why... since I see that the init function is defined here:
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/protocol-kit/src/Safe.ts#L100

Have you made sure to import this package using either yarn add @safe-global/protocol-kit or pnpm add @safe-global/protocol-kit?
Thank you in advance 
EDIT: Depending on your project ES configuration (e.g. { "type": "module" } in package.json or typescript target configuration) you might also need to do Safe.default.init() instead of Safe.init().
Please let me know if this worked.
Best, Louis
